# Express (NodeJS) failure to handle Post from Xamarin Android App

Tags: c#, node.js, express, post, xamarin

I've got a few devices that interact with an Express app on a local server. For the purposes of a prototype demo I'm trying to make this as simple as possible. Among many other things, my local server interacts with images, and image data in the /uploads folder thusly:

(Express/NodeJS code):

```
app.route('/uploads')
//Send File to Android
   .get( function (req, res) {
     var images = fs.readdirSync('./uploads');
     console.log(images[images.length-1]);

     var imgpath = path.resolve('./uploads/' + images[images.length-1]);
     res.sendFile(imgpath);
    //res.end('Image List Sent')
   })
 //Receive image chip data from Android
   .post( function (req, res) {
     Console.log("insideit");
     Console.log(req.body);

     res.end('got something?')
   });
```

This server code is receiving requests from C# Android code. The GET command works perfectly, so I will omit that Xamarin/C# code. The POST command from the android app is thus (In C#/Xamarin):

```
        var rxcui = "198840";
        string _url = string.Format(@"http://10.1.10.194:3000/uploads", rxcui);
        string datastr = "test";
        try
        {
            (new WebClient()).UploadString(_url, datastr);

        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Post Upload Error");
        }
    }
```

The server sees the post request, but returns 500. It appears that it's not routing properly, because It won't go into my post handling code and print a simple test string. Any thoughts on why the POST command is not being handled appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace res.end with res.send(). Something like this

```
.post( function (req, res) {
     Console.log("insideit");
     Console.log(req.body);

     res.send('got something?');
   });
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi there. No change in error. I still get "POST /uploads 500 1197.323 ms - 1591". Still not getting any of my print functions or any indication the post request is being handled by this block of code.

Comment: @GregoryHewitt Can you please give me exact text of error?